# Визуализация данных из БД c#

Tags: c#, графика, графы

Добрый день!
У меня имеется БД, в которой храится информация о связях объектов. Все объекты имеют один тип, и каждый объект связан с другими объектами. 
Пусть имеются два класса:

```
class Object
{
    public int Id{get;set;}
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public Object(int id, string name)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
    }
}

class Relation
{
    public Object obj1{get;set;}
    public Object obj2{get;set;}
    public Relation(Object o1, Object o2)
    {
        obj1 = o1;
        obj2 = o2;
    }
}
```

И пусть данные хранятся таким образом:

```
List<Relation> relations = new List<Relation>();
```

на основе имеющихся данных я реализовал генерацию DGML файла, который бы визуально отражал связи объектов.
Получился граф, например как этот: http://www.softwareprocessengineering.com/_SPDiag/DGMLNOGroups.jpg
Но проблема состоит в том, что в windows forms нет эелмента управления, который бы позволял отражать DGML файл прямо на форме, как и нет метода, который бы позволил конвертировать DGML в изображение.
Каким альтернативным путем я мог бы реализовать подобное изображение?
Пробовал реализовать вручную через Graphics, но у меня нет представления как отсортировать объекты таким образом, чтобы граф был упорядочен как в DGML и не вышла "каша-мала". Как можно реализовать DGML подобную визуализацию?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я думаю, что подойдет библиотека [GraphX](https://github.com/panthernet/GraphX)

В исходниках куча примеров по использованию

Comment: с GraphX возникла такая проблема, если у меня есть две связи вида объект1->объект2, и мне необходимо отразить их графически обе, строя каждую из них при помощи dataEdge = new DataEdge(o1, o2) { Text = line.Type }; (line.Type - тип связи) на самом графе отражается только одна связь, каким образом я могу отразить две? Изучаю документацию, но пока не столкнулся с ответом на такой вопрос.

Comment: Также я заметил, что если я установлю значение allowParallelEdges у графа на false, в таком случае я вижу только первую связь, а если true то только вторую. Таким образом они перекрывают друг друга, но необходимо видеть их одновременно.